# How to dump Hashmap data (variable key/value size) into a .csv file at a specific memory location in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, csv

My hashmap has `String` type as key and `ArrayList` type as value, example `{"v1"=[1.1,1.2,1.3], "v2"=[2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4]}` where `"v1"` and `"v2"` are keys. There are more than 40 keys (previously unknown size) and each key has a `ArrayList` which may not be uniform in size (size >200).
I want to write this hashmap data in the following format in a .csv file in my Android phone.

```
v1   v2 
1.1  2.1
1.2  2.2
1.3  2.3
```

Until now, my Hashmap had fixed key/array size and I used the following code snippet to dump the data:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
              
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/santobedi" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second);
                String csv = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/data.csv";
                try {
                    file_writer = new FileWriter(csv, true);

                    if (isReady == false) {  
                        String s = "v1, v2,\n";
                        file_writer.append(s);
                        isReady = true; // The columns heads are set
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Later, I'd append (row-wise) the values on a loop checking the Boolean value `isReady`. Now, the size of the key is not fixed, so I cannot set the column heads as before. I searched for a possible solution, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606376/write-data-from-hashmap-as-a-csv-file) question is almost similar to my situation. However, it is not related to memory location inside the Android phone and the accepted answer is still not solving my problem.

Any help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following approach:

```
 public FileWriter file_writer;
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Santobedi" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second);
                folder.mkdir();
                String csv = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/data.csv";
                try { file_writer = new FileWriter(csv, true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Later, a `writeToCSV` method is used to append data in the `file_writer` as follows:

```
public void writeToCsv() throws IOException {

        for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Float>>IwantItasColumn:myHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            String s = "";
           for(int i =0; i<IwantItasColumn.getValue().size();i++)
           {
               s = s+ ","+ String.valueOf(IwantItasColumn.getValue().get(i));
           }
           s = AccessPointId.getKey() + "," + s + "\n";
           file_writer.append(s);
        }

        try {
            file_writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

The above code snippet appends the data row-wise in the `data.csv` file (disregard to the size of the hashmap, size of keys, size of `ArrayList`). For example:

```
v1 1.1 1.2 1.3
v2 2.1 2.2 2.3
```

A simple row to column transformation in `Excel` gives me the required result.